Dynamical problem regarding radial and cross-radial acceleration
In a motion of two dimension, the radial and cross-radial components of acceleration are equal. Find the equation of the path.
Radial acceleration: $\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2$
Cross-radial acceleration: $\dfrac 1r\dfrac{d}{dt}(r^2\dot{\theta})$.
So $\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2=\dfrac 1r\dfrac{d}{dt}(r^2\dot{\theta})$
Here is where I am stuck. Here $r$ and $\theta$ are two variables. Since it is not said that the angular velocity is constant, we can't use $\dot{\theta}=\omega$. So how do I find the path?
